# Modifying ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods

Tags: class, activerecord, methods, collections, associations

I have a model

```
 class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tale_culture_joins
   has_many :cultures, through: :tale_culture_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true, index: true
   has_many :tale_purpose_joins
   has_many :purposes, through: :tale_purpose_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true, index: true
   has_many :tale_book_joins
   has_many :books, through: :tale_book_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true, index: true
   has_many :tale_keyword_joins
   has_many :keywords, through: :tale_keyword_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true, index: true
   has_many :tale_character_joins
   has_many :characters, through: :tale_character_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true, index: true
   has_many :tale_moral_joins
   has_many :morals, through: :tale_moral_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true
   has_many :values, through: :morals, index: true
   has_many :tale_event_joins
   has_many :events, through: :tale_event_joins, dependent: :destroy, crud: true

  end
```

I often have to access the association_ids for an instance object. i.e

tale.moral_ids
But I think rails treats [1,2] and [2,1] as the same
So if 
       tale.moral_ids # => [1,2]

From the front end the order is changed.
I cannot use

```
   tale.moral_ids= [2,1]
```

to make a change in the db.
I have to do the following

```
   tale.moral_ids = []
```

then

```
   tale.moral_ids = [2,1]
```

I have written controller code - Would like to put that in the model itself. How?

Also I need to put a default_scope on the join_table model on the id to ensure that tale.morals is not returned auto sorted by moral_ids rather by the order of insertion in the joins table.

How to override / patch / modify this rails behavior so that no other crashes happen.

I understand that collections might be like sets and order invariant. But my application needs the ordering functionality and I would not like to add extra logic but get things in the order i put them and work with the order directly.